# Ionic1 VAT Calculation

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic1 application and three inputs.

```
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <div class="input-label">
          Total (Inc VAT) £
        </div>
        <input type="number" ng-model="form.gross" placeholder="Total Including VAT">
      </label> 
      <label class="item item-input item-select">
        <div class="input-label">
          VAT Value
        </div>
        <select ng-model="form.vat">
          <option value="20" selected="">20%</option>
          <option value="0">0%</option>
          <option value="5">5%</option>
        </select>
      </label> 
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <div class="input-label">
          Amount (Ex VAT) £
        </div>
        <input type="number" ng-model="form.net" placeholder="Total Including VAT">
      </label>
```

- form.gross
- form.net
- form.vat

I'm trying to make a calculation based on the input to gross which works out the net value based on the VAT value %.

First problem - i can never get a selected option to be SELECTED. 
Second problem - in my controller the calculation for the net value doesn'nt update

**Controller**

```
$scope.form.gross = 0;
$scope.form.vat = 20;
$scope.form.vatValue = $scope.form.gross / 100 * $scope.form.vat;
$scope.form.net = $scope.form.gross - $scope.form.vatValue;
```

I thought due to the 2 way binding the application would change based on the values updated in the dom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your 1st problem: Just make use of ng-option & have an array of object containing value & labels for select. If you don't want to use that & want to use just conventional select then instead of using `selected=''` attribute on options, just initialise value of that field inside controller like

`$scope.form.vat= 20;`

(Use numbers as values, as anyway you're performing arithmetic operation on them)

For your 2nd problem just have ng-change directive on gross & vat fields and call the function inside which do the operation for finding vatvalue & net. So it'll be calculated every time you make changes in inputs as currently it's happening only one time on initial condition. So your function should be:

```
$scope.changed = function(){
    $scope.form.vatValue = $scope.form.gross / 100 * $scope.form.vat;
    $scope.form.net = $scope.form.gross - $scope.form.vatValue;
}
```

`ng-change="changed()"` Have this on both input fields (gross, vat).

Here's working codepen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LjPmmx?editors=1010.
Now as you've input field for 'net' so you might want to manipulate it, for that similarly you've to write another function to calculate gross based on constant vat value & changing net value and call it on ng-change of net field.